# Limit of $\frac{1}{r}\ln\left(1+r\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i \ln(x_i)+ \omicron(r)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let be $n \in \mathbb{N}$ arbitrary but fixed, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i =1$ and $\forall ~ 1\leq i \leq n$ we assume: $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

What is the limit of

$\lim\limits_{r\to 0}~\frac{1}{r}\ln\left(1+r\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i \ln(x_i)+ \omicron(r)\right)$, where $\lim\limits_{r\to 0}\frac{\omicron(r)}{r}=0$?

I tried some manipulations and the theorem of L'Hospital but it only got worse...

Comment: This is not well stated. Is $n$ fixed? What are the $x_i?$ What are the $p_i?$

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$S(r)=r\sum_{i=1}^np_i\ln(x_i)$$

we have
$$\lim_{r\to 0}(S(r)+o(r))=0$$

thus

$$\color{red}{\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\ln\Bigl(1+S(r)+o(r)\Bigr)}{S(r)+o(r)}=1}$$

therefore, the limit is $$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{S(r)+o(r)}{r}=\sum_{i=1}^np_i\ln(x_i)$$
because

$$\frac{\ln(1+S(r)+o(r))}{r}=$$
$$\color{red}{\frac{\ln(1+S(r)+o(r))}{S(r)+o(r)}}\frac{S(r)+o(r)}{r}.$$

and 
$$\frac{S(r)}{r}+\frac{o(r)}{r}=$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^np_i\ln(x_i)+\frac{o(r)}{r}$$

Comment: Can you explain to me the step that follows "the limit is ..." a little bit more? Why can we conclude the limit of $\lim_{r\to0}\frac{S(r)+o(r)}{r}$ from $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\ln\Bigl(1+S(r)+o(r)\Bigr)}{S(r)+o(r)}=1$ ?

Comment: @Philipp I just added some lines in the end. hope will help.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanations :)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to show the statement with the theorem of L'Hospital? The problem is that when applying this theorem there appears a term $\omicron'(r)$ and I am not sure what happens to this term when $r \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Remembering that
$$
\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+r)}{r} = 1
$$

we get
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+r\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i \ln(x_i)+ \omicron(r)\right)}{r} &= \lim_{r \to 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+r\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i \ln(x_i)+ \omicron(r)\right)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  p_i \ln(x_i)+ \omicron(r)}\cdot  \frac{r\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i \ln(x_i)+ \omicron(r)}{r}
\end{split}
$$

Can you continue from here?